# How Do I Write A "Count By" Method Name Query In Spring Data

Tags: spring-data

So I know that I can write an interface like the one below and Spring Data will automatically generate the necessary database access stuff for me.  Now what I'd like to do is add a new method name that will count the number of entities that match a set of criteria.

```
public interface EventRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<EventRegistration, String>
{    
    List<EventRegistration> findByUser_EmailAddress(String email);

    int countByEvent_Code(String eventCode);
}
```

As of now the countBy method causes this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property count found for type com.brazencareerist.brazenconnect.model.relational.EventRegistration
```

What's the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works as expected as of the [just released](http://blog.springsource.org/2013/06/10/first-milestone-of-spring-data-release-train-babbage-arrived/) Spring Data JPA 1.4.0.M1.

Comment: yay exactly what we need!!

Comment: hey oli! the link is dead

Comment: Oliver link is dead. Kindly, can you provide another one?